# XSL to Excel: Choose not processing formula

Tags: excel, xslt, formula, xsl-choose, ss

I declared a variable with a simple Excel formula (not the formula I will eventually use, just something simple for testing)

```
<xsl:variable name="nistcci" ss:Formula="=RC19"></xsl:variable>
```

Then I am trying to use a Choose to determine if the attribute data is empty, then return based on that determination.

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="stig_rules"> <!-- IA Control(s) -->
<Data ss:Type="String">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE[node()='IA_Controls']/../ATTRIBUTE_DATA != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE[node()='IA_Controls']/../ATTRIBUTE_DATA" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$nistcci"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</Data>
```

This works if I do something simple like:

> `<xsl:variable name="nistcci">sean</xsl:variable>`

But isn't working with a formula within a referenced variable.

Thanks for the help. Sean.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want your variable to contain.

It is quite clear that the `xsl:variable` instruction cannot have a `ss:Formula` attribute, or any other attribute except `select` and (in XSLT 2.0) `as`.

Your variable needs to be constructed as:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="myExpr"/>
```

where `myExpr` must be a valid XPath expression.

Alternatively, you could use something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar">
  <xsl:attribute name="ss:Formula">=RC19</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:variable>
```

to construct a variable that holds an attribute.

Comment: Using only XSL 1.0I'm trying to get the "=RC19" to populate into the resultant Excel worksheet as an Excel formula, not just as text.

Comment: Using only XSL 1.0.   I'm trying to get the "=RC19" to populate into the resultant Excel worksheet as an Excel formula, not just as text. I'm trying to get this into the <xsl:otherwise> portion.  Even the variable+attribute proposed above doesn't populate the excel cell(s). They are still blank.

Comment: @SeanPerryman AFAIK, in order to have a formula, you need to add a `ss:Formula` attribute to the `ss:Cell` element. Your `xsl:choose` is a child of `ss:Data`, that's too late.